# count the total grouped record in pipeline using golang mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using golang and mongodb.Below is my go code

```
matchStage := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{'country':'India'}}
groupByStage := bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
        "_id":             "$state",
        "city_count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
    }}
pipeline := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        matchStage,
        groupByStage,
    })

 document := []bson.M{}
 err = pipeline.All(&document)
```

I am getting each state with city count but I want to get total no of grouped states.This is only example but I want to get data similar like that.So there is any solution beside loop to get total count of grouped data not for each grouped data count?

My Output is like
`{'state1':3,'state2':4,'state3':1}` but i want only `'3' as count`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like you're using mgo or some other version of it. I would highly suggest that you use the [official go driver from mongodb](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc).

There are two approaches to answer your question:

If you just want the count isn't this what you basically need:

```
states := []string{}
err := getCollection.Find(bson.M{'country': 'India'}).Distinct("state", &states)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", len(states))
```

If you want the number of states along with count in each state - maybe add a second group.

```
matchStage := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{'country':'India'}}
groupByStage := bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
        "_id": bson.M{
                 "country": "$country",
                 "state": "$state",
        },
        "city_count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
    }}
groupByStage2 := bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
        "_id": "$_id.country",
        "city_counts": bson.M{
            "$push": bson.M{
                 "state": "$_id.state",
                 "city_count": "$city_count",
             },
        },
        "state_count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
    }}
pipeline := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        matchStage,
        groupByStage,
        groupByStage2,
    })

 document := []bson.M{}
 err = pipeline.All(&document)
```

You should get something like this

```
[{
    "_id": "India",
    "city_counts": [{'state1':3,'state2':4,'state3':1}],
    "state_count": 3
}]
```

Comment: how we can extract data from single document either using `document := bson.M{}` or ` var document interface{}`. I just want to get count only and return into response.